# FontAwesome 5 - SVG&JS - pseudo elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, font-awesome-5

Trying to use new Font Awesome 5 in SVG&JS combination in ::before element

Already tried to find solutions but it still not work correctly.

In head i got script activating the function and script.

```
<script>FontAwesomeConfig = { searchPseudoElements: true };</script>
<script src="fontawesome/js/all.js"></script>
```

CSS looks like this (also tried with or without font-weight 400/900, other font families and still found solution)

```
<style>
    .regular {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .regular:before {
        content:'\f2bb';
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Regular';
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        font-weight: 900;
    }
</style>
```

After loading the page JS create SVG icon, but not delete the ::before element so i got black square and correct icon after it.

Someone find solution (except CDNs) how to use it corecctly?

Comment: check the second duplicate to see how to do with the JS version .. let me know if it still not working

Comment: Font family is ok..... Problem is with JS ( not deleting the pseudo element before ) (i want to use SVG not classical webfont way )

Comment: yes check the second duplicate, I face the same issue ;) .. you need to hide it manually (or maybe there is another trick, but it's the one I found)

Comment: Yeah just checked it and its working. Rly weird solution but works. Thanks for help.

Comment: yes and am pretty sure there is something else to do ... but still didn't find for the new version